# conditional constraint in optimization while using cplex

Tags: java, cplex

I am developing a cplex model in concert with Java and I need a conditional constraint but it seems that the `cplex.ifthen` code is not executed at all.

I want that if an element of an array is equal to one, then one element of the same column number should be equal to one.

Here is my code. Basically, I have created two matrices with the same dimensions. First, I have chosen the minimum from the first matrix, that is 4. Now I want to choose the minimum element from that column. For that I am using `cplex.ifthen` but it is not working.

```
package sch;

import ilog.concert.*;
import ilog.cplex.*;

import ilog.concert.IloException;
import ilog.concert.IloLinearNumExpr;
import ilog.concert.IloNumVar;
import ilog.cplex.IloCplex;

public class Firsttry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        schedule();

    }

    public static void schedule() {
        int exp = 3;
        int imp = 5;
        double[] volI = { 10.5, 5.0, 15.5, 16, 2.0 };
        double shipv = 0.25;
        double[][] days = { { 115, 7, 9, 8, 7 }, { 555, 14, 8, 7, 12 }, { 112, 6, 8, 10, 4 } };
        try {

            IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
            // variable
            IloNumVar[][] x = new IloNumVar[exp][imp];
            IloNumVar[][] y = new IloNumVar[exp][imp];
            for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {

                    x[e][i] = cplex.boolVar();
                    y[e][i] = cplex.boolVar();
                }
            }
            IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();
            for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {
                    objective.addTerm(days[e][i], x[e][i]);
                    objective.addTerm(days[e][i], y[e][i]);

                }

            }
            cplex.addMinimize(objective);
            // CONSTRAINTS
            // constraint .....1
            IloLinearNumExpr expr1 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
            // IloLinearNumExpr expr2 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
            for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {
                    expr1.addTerm(1, x[e][i]);

                }
            }
            cplex.addEq(expr1, 1);
            // constraint .....2
            // if
            IloLinearNumExpr[][] rowexp = new IloLinearNumExpr[exp][imp];
            IloLinearNumExpr[] colexp = new IloLinearNumExpr[imp];
            IloConstraint[][] rowconst = new IloConstraint[exp][imp];
            IloConstraint[] colconst = new IloConstraint[imp];
            // if
            for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                // rowexp[e] = cplex.linearNumExpr();
                for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {
                    rowexp[e][i] = cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    rowexp[e][i].addTerm(1, x[e][i]);
                    rowconst[e][i] = cplex.eq(1, rowexp[e][i]);
                }
                // rowconst[e] = cplex.eq(1, rowexp[e]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {
                colexp[i] = cplex.linearNumExpr();
                for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                    // colexp[i] = cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    colexp[i].addTerm(1, y[e][i]);

                }
                colconst[i] = cplex.eq(1, colexp[i]);
            }

            for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {
                    cplex.ifThen(rowconst[e][i], colconst[i]);
                }
            }

            if (cplex.solve()) {
                System.out.println("obje =" + cplex.getObjValue());
                for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {

                        // System.out.println(" =" + cplex.getValue(y[e][i]));
                        System.out.print(cplex.getValue(y[e][i]) + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                }
                System.out.printf("%n%n%n");
                for (int e = 0; e < exp; ++e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < imp; ++i) {

                        // System.out.println(" =" + cplex.getValue(y[e][i]));
                        System.out.print(cplex.getValue(x[e][i]) + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("obje =" + cplex.getObjValue());

            }

        } catch (IloException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test your code or study your formulation, but it looks like your problem comes from the following line:

```
cplex.ifThen(rowconst[e][i], colconst[i]);
```

As the documentation for [ifThen](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#ifThen(ilog.concert.IloConstraint,%20ilog.concert.IloConstraint)) says, it *returns a constraint*. It does not add it to the model. To fix this, you can just do something like the following:

```
cplex.add(cplex.ifThen(rowconst[e][i], colconst[i]));
```

Also, for an example of how to use `ifThen`, you might want to take a look at the `FoodManufact.java` program that comes with CPLEX.